# MapView NullPointerException in onCreate only with newest GooglePlayServices

Tags: java, android, xml, google-play-services, android-mapview

I have been maintaining an app utilizing a MapView, and recently I have been getting NullPointerExceptions when attempting to call the onCreate() method of the MapView. Strangely, this only happens on newer versions of Google Play Services. When I revert the version to factory defaults, the MapView works without a hitch. That is to say, works on 9.8.79, does not on 14.3.66. Changing the version of Play Services on all production handhelds is not an option.

**What I have tried**

1. Checking the API key: Not the issue. Couldn't have been this anyways as it would not have worked with an older version of Play Services either.
2. Updating play-services-maps dependency from 8.4.0(default from ye olde days) to 16.0.0, the most recent. Although this clears up the exception, the MapView never manages to finish initializing. All it does is render a black space with the text "Google Play services are updating" despite the fact that it was just updated to 14.3.66.
3. Pre-Initializing with MapsInitializer.initialize(); This should not be needed as the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) say that getMapAsync() does this automatically, but I gave it a shot anyways. No change in behavior.
4. Checked layout files. I was really hoping that somehow this was the problem but findViewById() returned a valid reference so no luck there.

There are several questions out there with similar titles, so I would like to preempt the storm of [duplicate] tags now. Every other question I have seen had different details in the stack trace, and the answers suggested either did not apply or did not work for my issue.

**LogCat**

```
10-11 10:36:59.644 2386-2386/net.xconsulting.fairtrak E/DynamiteLoaderImpl: Error creating module context: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
10-11 10:36:59.680 2386-2386/net.xconsulting.fairtrak E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.xconsulting.fairtrak, PID: 2386
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.xconsulting.fairtrak/net.xconsulting.fairtrak.activity.NotesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1469)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.contains(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContentResolver.checkLeakDetectIgnoreList(ContentResolver.java:2695)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1178)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:958)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:811)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:765)
        at tns.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366020@14.3.66 (040406-213742215):33)
        at tns.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366020@14.3.66 (040406-213742215):11)
        at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.createModuleContextNoCrashUtils(:com.google.android.gms@14366020@14.3.66 (040406-213742215):11)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.b(:com.google.android.gms@14366020@14.3.66 (040406-213742215):12)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366020@14.3.66 (040406-213742215):53)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366020@14.3.66 (040406-213742215):76)
        at oky.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366020@14.3.66 (040406-213742215):1)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366020@14.3.66 (040406-213742215):8)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms@14366020@14.3.66 (040406-213742215):1)
        at actl.a(:com.google.android.gms@14366020@14.3.66 (040406-213742215):21)
        at cje.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms@14366020@14.3.66 (040406-213742215):3)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:392)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zzzW(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
        at net.xconsulting.fairtrak.activity.NotesActivity.onCreate(NotesActivity.java:70)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2613) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1469) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5692) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:769)
```

**Code**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);

        MapView mapView = findViewById(R.id.noteMap);

        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

**Layout**

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/noteMap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**Gradle Dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    //also tried implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Are you using those codes inside `NotesActivity` class? Also try to use the latest version.

Comment: Yes, That is inside of the NotesActivity class. I did try the latest version as well. As I mentioned above it just caused other problems